# nested object in graphcool

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, graphcool

I have a model like this:

```
  type User @model {
    id: ID! @isUnique
  }
```

Now I want to add a nested object:

```
type User @model {
   id: ID! @isUnique
   position: {
      lat: Int
      lng: Int 
    }
}
```

but I get a error from Graphcool,

```
{", expected IgnoredNoComment, ImplementsInterfaces or Directives (line 4, column 11):
 type User @model {
      ^
```

Why? can't I pass a nested object? In this way I can update the mutation simply passing the object with lat and lng. What is wrong with this?

Comment: did answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nested structure you need to define one for type variable like below

```
type User @model {
   id: ID! @isUnique
   position: Position
}
type Position {
  lat: Int
  lng: Int 
}
```